# Creating Bulk Objects from Rails Form - Using Integer to Set Amount of Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In Rails 5.1, I want to use a form that will create objects based on the number of objects specified in the form.  As an example, I have the following fields:

```
<%= form_for(@object, remote: true, html: {"data-type" => :json, id: "object_new"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Object Name", for: "object_name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, type: "text", id: "object_name" %>

  <%= f.label :amount, "Amount of objects", for: "object_amount" %>
  <%= f.number_field :amount, type: "number", id: "object_amount" %>

  <%= f.label :start_at, "Start Count At...", for: "object_start_at" %>
  <%= f.number_field :start_at, type: "number", id: "object_start_at" %>

  <%= f.button 'Create New Object(s)', id: 'new_objects_submit' %>

<%end %>
```

My model for objects looks like this:

```
class Object < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :amount, :start_at
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

The basic idea is that you give the objects you wish to create a `name`, and you set the amount of objects you wish to create with the `amount` field.  The `start_at` field denotes the number to start at.

So say the name is `Basic`, the amount is `3`, and the start_at is `2`.  The objects created would be:

```
Basic02
Basic03
Basic04
```

My question is how could I accomplish this in the most Rails-friendly way possible?  I was thinking of adding private methods in the controller to parse out the data to fit my needs, and calling on those methods in the `create` method of the controller, but I feel like this may bloat my controller too much, and could cause a nightmare when I attempt to validate my params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your create action you'd want to do something like this:

```
def create

  @object.amount.times do |i|
    object = Object.new do |object|
      name = @object.name.strip # => "Basic"
      number = (@object.start_at + i + 1) # => 2
      formatted_number = number < 10 ? "0#{number}" : number # => "02"
      object.name = @object.name.strip + formatted_number # => "Basic02"
    end
    object.save!
  end

end
```

I've done a similar thing a few times, and this type of thing tends to mutate into an incomprehensible mess.

I'd suggest sticking this logic into a service object. That way you can abstract away any related logic and error handling, without bloating your controller, i.e.:

`ObjectsController#create`:

```
def create
  if CreateObjects.call(@object)
    respond_to do |format|
      format ... #success
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format ... #failure
    end
  end
end
```

and the `CreateObjects` service:

```
# app/services/create_objects.rb 

class CreateObjects
  def self.call(object)
    new(object).call
  end

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def call
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do # will only save if _all_ the objects are saved
      @object.amount.times do |i|
        create_object(i)
      end
    end
  end

  def create_object(i)
    object = Object.new do |object|
      name = @object.name.strip # => "Basic"
      object.name = @object.name.strip + formatted_number(i) # => "Basic02"
    end
    object.save!
  end

  def formatted_number(i)
    number = (@object.start_at + i + 1) # => 2
    number < 10 ? "0#{number}" : number # => "02"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had no idea about service objects in Rails.  How would you go about fitting this into the `respond_to do |format|` - that is, if one `object.save!` were to fail, make the entire form submission fail and respond in json/html?

Comment: You're welcome @Wes, I've updated the example above. If you want to make sure _all_ objects are saved, you could wrap it in a transaction (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html for more info).

Comment: Re: dealing with `respond_to` stuff — If no errors are raised, (I think) it will return `true` — in which case you can check for true, and return a success message. If any errors are raised, you'll want to return them from the `CreateObjects` service. I'll update the example later on this evening :)

Comment: It looks like the ActiveRecord transaction will simply return the block regardless if it succeeds or fails, and not true or false.  I was experimenting using `rescue` to get out of the errors, but it would mean using custom json messages as responses, which I don't necessarily like.  I'm still playing around with it...